# ES6 Modules and Webpack

Tags: webpack, es6-modules

I'm learning about ES6 Modules and Webpack things, but I still didn't quite understand something from these things.

1. When we should or shouldn't use it?
2. Is it good to have massive tons of files and link them with `export` `import`?
3. What is a good practice for me to understand it better?

I appreciate any kind of response, thanks before.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have something to share with you inline:

> When we should or shouldn't use it?

`esmodule` is also known as `esnext` which is the next version of Javascript which means you should use it. Regarding to `webpack`, it's a powerful tool to not only build the js code to run against browser but also combine your assets together (images/fonts/...) so that it can work together. In short, it would take around 5mins to build a webapp as write code as esm style + use webpack to build code run for browser.

> Is it good to have massive tons of files and link them with export import?

This is how are modules working so there's no issue why doing that. It would be even easier to manage and test a module if you keep it small. In short, no problem for multiple files with `import/export` at all.

> What is a good practice for me to understand it better?

There are hundreds of document regarding to `esnext` + `webpack` if you search for them. Visiting the official website to read is also a good way to go.